# unable to understand the output of the commands in np.arange

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
i=np.arange(0,2.1,0.5,dtype='int8')
print(i)
[0 0 0 0 0]


g=np.arange(0.5,2.1,0.5,dtype='int8')
print(g)
[0 1 2 3]


n=np.arange(257,260,0.5,dtype='int16')
print(n)
[257 257 257 257 257 257]

p=np.arange(257,260,0.5,dtype='int8')
print(p)
[1 1 1 1 1 1]


o=np.arange(257.5,260,0.5,dtype='int16')
print(o)
[257 258 259 260 261]

q=np.arange(257.5,260,0.5,dtype='int8')
print(q)
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to specify a fractional step, and then tell to truncated values to integer.  Since floating point values aren't exact, especially in `arange` truncation can give unexpected results.

Comment: Please be more accurate regarding the question- what is confusing you and what you expected to happen VS what actually happened

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the reply. I know it doesn't make sense but I tried to see how numpy responds to such cases. Especially why is it returning 0 in starting from 0 but its returning 1,2,3,4 when starting from 0.5.

i=np.arange(0,2.1,0.5,dtype='int8')
print(i)
[0 0 0 0 0]


g=np.arange(0.5,2.1,0.5,dtype='int8')
print(g)
[0 1 2 3]

Comment: Without studying the `c` source code we can only hypothesize when values are truncated to 'int8'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.arange` is compiled code.  Unless we can find and study the C source, we don't know exactly what it's doing.  Tests like yours only let us test hypotheses.

First a float case, as expected:

```
In [124]: np.arange(0,2.1,0.5)
Out[124]: array([0. , 0.5, 1. , 1.5, 2. ])
```

And converting those floats to int after:

```
In [125]: np.arange(0,2.1,0.5).astype('int')
Out[125]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2])
```

Sometimes this produces unexpected values, if for example, the 1.0 was really 0.99999.

It's less obvious what happens when the dtype is set within `arange`:

```
In [126]: np.arange(0,2.1,0.5, int)
Out[126]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

It's almost as though the number of values were set as with the floats, the the truncation to int occurs iteratively.

```
0, 0+.5=>.5=>0, 0+.5=>0, etc
```

Start at .5:

```
In [127]: np.arange(0.5,2.1,0.5)
Out[127]: array([0.5, 1. , 1.5, 2. ])
In [128]: np.arange(0.5,2.1,0.5).astype(int)
Out[128]: array([0, 1, 1, 2])

In [129]: np.arange(0.5,2.1,0.5,int)
Out[129]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

0.5 =>0; .5+.5=>1; bit 1+.5=?  nope that doesn't work.
```

So not only can float steps create small float precision difference, but it you throw in an incompatible `dtype`, the whole iteration becomes unpredictable.  It's not clear what values get converted to `int`.  Clearly it isn't simply a post truncation as with `astype(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Numpy Arange documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use numpy.linspace for these cases.

Since for example your first example uses a float `2.1` it gives unexpected outcomes. Try using [Numpy Linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace)

Using linspace for your first example makes maybe more sense:

```
import numpy as np
i=np.linspace(0,2.1, num=3,dtype='int8')
print(i)
```

```
[0 1 2]
```

or without dtype='int8'

```
[0. 1.05 2.1]
```

Comment: yes I saw that it is going to give unexpected results. Will be using linspace only. Thank you